# android list refreshing only from one void and not from another

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

this is quite odd to me: in my project (which by the way is derived from Yaxim, so it's a chat app for android), I'm trying to implement writing notification through the messageeventlistener. I do receive the notification event. To make it appear in the listview (which is in another class) I'm adding a row in the database, as if it were a message (only the text is "..."). I've added a counter and the row is properly inserted in the db (subsequently the row is deleted from the db when the actual message comes). The notifychanges is also called properly. The strange thing is that despite all of this the row doesn't appear in the listview. If I move the procedure a few lines below, on the packetlistener for the regular messages, it gets inserted. However I cannot leave it like that because the packetlistener doesn't receive properly all composing notifications, so it doesn't work all the time for that purpose. Also, while the writing notification is properly inserted into the db, if I keep the procedure in the messageEventNotificationListener() the writing notification message does not get deleted when the actual message arrives (and the iCount keeps increasing); if I put the procedure in the packetListener it does (hence iCount equals 0 after the message is pushed into the db)

This is the messageeventlistener:

```
private void messageEventNotificationListener(){
    // Create a MessageEventManager
    if (mMessageEventManager == null)
        mMessageEventManager = new MessageEventManager(mXMPPConnection);
      // Add the listener that will react to the event notifications
    mMessageEventManager.addMessageEventNotificationListener(new MessageEventNotificationListener() {
          public void deliveredNotification(String from, String packetID) {
              Log.d(TAG, "The message has been delivered (" + from + ", " + packetID + ")");
          }

          public void displayedNotification(String from, String packetID) {
              Log.d(TAG, "The message has been displayed (" + from + ", " + packetID + ")");
          }

          public void composingNotification(String from, String packetID) {
              Log.d(TAG, "The message's receiver is composing a reply (" + from + ", " + packetID + ")");
              //controlla se l'utente non sta già scrivendo 
              String selection = ChatConstants.JID + " = '" + from + "' AND " +
                        ChatConstants.DELIVERY_STATUS + " = " + ChatConstants.DS_WRITING;

                Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(ChatProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                            new String[] { "count(" + ChatConstants._ID + ")" },
                            selection, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int iCount = cursor.getInt(0);
                //if (iCount == 0)
                //{
                    addChatMessageToDB(ChatConstants.INCOMING, from, "...", ChatConstants.DS_WRITING, System.currentTimeMillis(), packetID);

                //}

          }

          public void offlineNotification(String from, String packetID) {
              Log.d(TAG, "The message's receiver is offline (" + from + ", " + packetID + ")");
          }

          public void cancelledNotification(String from, String packetID) {
              Log.d(TAG, "The message's receiver cancelled composing a reply (" + from + ", " + packetID + ")");


          }
      });   

}
```

and here is the packetlistener:

```
private void registerMessageListener() {
    // do not register multiple packet listeners
    if (mPacketListener != null)
        mXMPPConnection.removePacketListener(mPacketListener);

    PacketTypeFilter filter = new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class);

    mPacketListener = new PacketListener() {
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            try {
            if (packet instanceof Message) {
                Message msg = (Message) packet;
                String chatMessage = msg.getBody();

                DeliveryReceipt dr = (DeliveryReceipt)msg.getExtension("received", DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE);
                if (dr != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "got delivery receipt for " + dr.getId());
                    changeMessageDeliveryStatus(dr.getId(), ChatConstants.DS_DELIVERED);
                }


                if (chatMessage == null)
                    return;

                if (msg.getType() == Message.Type.error) {
                    chatMessage = "<Error> " + chatMessage;
                }

                long ts;
                DelayInfo timestamp = (DelayInfo)msg.getExtension("delay", "urn:xmpp:delay");
                if (timestamp == null)
                    timestamp = (DelayInfo)msg.getExtension("x", "jabber:x:delay");
                if (timestamp != null)
                    ts = timestamp.getStamp().getTime();
                else
                    ts = System.currentTimeMillis();

                String fromJID = getJabberID(msg.getFrom());

                //elimina il messaggio "writing" se esiste
                     deleteWritingChatMessageFromDB(fromJID);

                    if (msg.getExtension("request", DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE) != null) {
                        // got XEP-0184 request, send receipt
                        sendReceipt(msg.getFrom(), msg.getPacketID());
                    }

                    addChatMessageToDB(ChatConstants.INCOMING, fromJID, chatMessage, ChatConstants.DS_NEW, ts, msg.getPacketID());
                    mServiceCallBack.newMessage(fromJID, chatMessage);
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // SMACK silently discards exceptions dropped from processPacket :(
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to process packet:");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    };

    mXMPPConnection.addPacketListener(mPacketListener, filter);
}
```

and finally the insert and delete method

```
private void addChatMessageToDB(int direction, String JID,
        String message, int delivery_status, long ts, String packetID) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(ChatConstants.DIRECTION, direction);
    values.put(ChatConstants.JID, JID);
    values.put(ChatConstants.MESSAGE, message);
    values.put(ChatConstants.DELIVERY_STATUS, delivery_status);
    values.put(ChatConstants.DATE, ts);
    values.put(ChatConstants.PACKET_ID, packetID);

    Uri noteUri = mContentResolver.insert(ChatProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
    //mContentResolver.notifyChange(noteUri, null);
}

private void deleteWritingChatMessageFromDB(String JID) {
    int count = mContentResolver.delete(ChatProvider.CONTENT_URI,
            ChatConstants.JID + " = ? AND " + ChatConstants.MESSAGE + " = ? AND " + ChatConstants.DELIVERY_STATUS + " = ?", new String[] { JID, "...", "3" });
    debugLog("deleteWritingChatMessageEntryFromDB: Deleted " + count + " entries");

}
```

both these methods get called into the ChatProvider class and end with
         getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(url, null);

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was different: I posting this just in case someone else runs in the same issue. The message was infact inserted into the db, but while the packetlistener returns only the jid, the messageeventlistener returns the jid with the resource at the end as well, which needed to be taken away before the insert. Done that, the message appeared in the list. Also: the code I posted is not completely correct to handle the messageEvent. The listeners need to be called from inside the packetListener directly.